# Java: Misplaced candidate list when using Chinese (Traditional) - New Phonetic keyboard

Tags: java, windows, swing, ime

I'm attempting to use the Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan), Chinese (Traditional) - New Phonetic keyboard on an English (US) Windows 7. When I type into a Java Swing-based text area, the candidate list is showing up on the bottom-right of my screen, regardless of where the text area is positioned on the screen. When I'm not using a Java program, the candidate list shows up in the correct place, directly under the text I'm typing.

Has anybody else run into this behavior and found a workaround for it? I haven't found other reports of this behavior online.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**System Details:**

- Microsoft New Phonetic IME 10.1 (10.1.7601.0)

  - Chinese input mode
  - Either half or full shape (doesn't matter)
  - Standard keyboard layout
- Windows 7, 64-bit (same happens on 32-bit)
- Affects Java 6, 7, and 8
- Affects Swing and JavaFX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually find similar problems reported, but most of them were related to Japanese IMEs and have already been fixed in the JDK. I didn't find any reports specific to this Chinese IME, but I did find a workaround in case it's useful for others.

The brief summary is that I listen for the WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION Windows message. When I see that, I locate the IME candidate window, move it to the location I want, and override its WindowProc to prevent further moves. During composition I also listen for WM_KEYDOWN events because I no longer received any WM_IME messages while the user was composing, even though the candidate window closes and gets recreated several times throughout composition. When I receive the WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITON message, I stop listening for WM_KEYDOWN messages.

As an alternative approach, I tried sending a WM_IME_CONTROL message with the IMC_SETCANDIDATEPOS command to move the candidate window, but this particular IME seems to ignore it.

I used JNA (https://github.com/twall/jna) to override the WindowProc on both the window containing my text area as well as the IME candidate window.

The code snippet below is an example of the workaround.

```
hwndMain = WIN_INSTANCE.FindWindow(null, "Main Window");

// Note the existing WindowProc so we can restore it later.
prevWndProc = new BaseTSD.LONG_PTR((long) WIN_INSTANCE.GetWindowLong(hwndMain, WinUser.GWL_WNDPROC));

// Register a new WindowProc that we will use to intercept IME messages.
mainListener = new WindowsCallbackListener() {
    @Override
    public int callback(int hWnd, int uMsg, int uParam, int lParam) {
        if (uMsg == WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION || (imeComposing && uMsg == WM_KEYDOWN)) {
            imeComposing = true;

            final WinDef.HWND hwndIme = WIN_INSTANCE.FindWindow("SYSIME7_READING_UI", null);

            if (hwndIme != null && !hwndIme.equals(imeWindow)) {
                // We found an IME window that is not the same as the last one. We assume the last one was
                // closed. We need to register our callback with the new window.
                imeWindow = hwndIme;

                final Point imeWindowLocation = getImeWindowLocation();
                WIN_INSTANCE.MoveWindow(hwndIme, imeWindowLocation.x, imeWindowLocation.y, 0, 0, true);

                final BaseTSD.LONG_PTR prevWndProcIme =
                        new BaseTSD.LONG_PTR((long) WIN_INSTANCE.GetWindowLong(hwndIme, WinUser.GWL_WNDPROC));

                imeListener = new WindowsCallbackListener() {
                    @Override
                    public int callback(int hWnd, int uMsg, int uParam, int lParam) {
                        if (uMsg == WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING) {
                            final WindowPosition pos = new WindowPosition(new Pointer((long)lParam));
                            pos.read();
                            pos.flags |= SWP_NOMOVE;
                            pos.write();
                        }

                        // Call the window's actual WndProc so the events get processed.
                        return WIN_INSTANCE.CallWindowProc(prevWndProcIme, hWnd, uMsg, uParam, lParam);
                    }
                };

                // Set the WndProc function to use our callback listener instead of the window's one.
                WIN_INSTANCE.SetWindowLong(hwndIme, WinUser.GWL_WNDPROC, imeListener);
            }
        }
        else if (uMsg == WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION) {
            // We can discard the IME listener since its window is closed. If another one gets opened, we'll
            // create a new listener.
            imeListener = null;
            imeComposing = false;
        }

        // Call the window's previous WindowProc so the event continues to get processed.
        return WIN_INSTANCE.CallWindowProc(prevWndProc, hWnd, uMsg, uParam, lParam);
    }
};

// Set the WindowProc function to use our WindowProc so the event continues to get processed.
WIN_INSTANCE.SetWindowLong(hwndMain, WinUser.GWL_WNDPROC, mainListener);
```

The code above assumes the following definitions:

```
private static final MyUser32 WIN_INSTANCE = MyUser32.INSTANCE;
private static final int SWP_NOMOVE = 2;
private static final int WM_KEYDOWN = 256;
private static final int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 70;
private static final int WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION = 270;
private static final int WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION = 269;
private WinDef.HWND hwndMain;
private BaseTSD.LONG_PTR prevWndProc;

// Keep references to these listeners so they don't get garbage-collected.
private WindowsCallbackListener mainListener;
private WindowsCallbackListener imeListener;

private boolean imeComposing;
private WinDef.HWND imeWindow;

public static class WindowPosition extends Structure {
    public WinDef.HWND hwnd;
    public WinDef.HWND hwndInsertAfter;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int cx;
    public int cy;
    public int flags;

    public WindowPosition(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
    }

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("hwnd", "hwndInsertAfter", "x", "y", "cx", "cy", "flags");
    }
}

private interface MyUser32 extends User32 {
    MyUser32 INSTANCE = (MyUser32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", MyUser32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    int CallWindowProc(BaseTSD.LONG_PTR prevWndProc, int hWnd, int uMsg, int uParam, int lParam);
    int SetWindowLong(HWND hwnd, int nIndex, BaseTSD.LONG_PTR listener) throws LastErrorException;
    int SetWindowLong(HWND hwnd, int nIndex, WindowsCallbackListener listener) throws LastErrorException;
}

private interface WindowsCallbackListener extends Callback, StdCall {
    int callback(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
}
```